# Tapestry: How to create stacked JqPlotBar chart

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart, tapestry

How do I create a stacked JqPlotBar chart in Tapestry? This is what I have tried.

```
List<TextValueDataItem> list1 = CollectionFactory.newList();
List<List<TextValueDataItem>> dataList = CollectionFactory.newList();

list1.add(new TextValueDataItem("Test1", 50));
list1.add(new TextValueDataItem("Test1", 60));

dataList.add(list1);
return dataList;
```

The result I get is a bar chart with one color until 60, with points label at 50 and 60. There is also no legend.
 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now an example of stacked bar chart at https://github.com/got5/tapestry5-jqPlot. 
I have a problem when trying to package the project using maven mvn package. It is trying to search for files under folder org\got5\tapestry5\jquery\jqplot\jquery\jqplot_core\jquery\jqplot\v1_0_8 but the folder in your tapestry-jqplot jar file is capital V1_0_8. You need to change it to small letter v1_0_8 for the jar file to work.